# how to show different product names based on color in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Here is the sql query for showing the result

```
SELECT  pd.SPDNO,bike_details.Cost, pd.Month_Name,pd.Company_Name,
bike_details.Product,pd.Quantity,pd.Bill_Amount,pd.Due_Date 
FROM payment_details pd INNER JOIN bike_details ON pd.SPDNO = bike_details.SPDNO WHERE pd.SPDNO='5000'
```

Here is the output

[image]

In the image product columns has 10 bikes and color is 4 red and 6 black now i want to show  that records on single row based on different bike color

I also used group by but it did not give me the desired output

Expected result should be like this

```
Order ID    Company Name    Product                           Quantity   Per Bike Cost  Month   Total Cost Due Date
5000        Memon Motors    SUPER STAR (SS-70cc)M.C Red(4),
                            SUPER STAR (SS-70cc)M.C Black(6)     10         47000        June    470000  2020-07-01
```

Any Help would be appreciated  & thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can group by the select columns and put a count at the end to get the (4) and (6)

```
  SELECT  pd.SPDNO,bike_details.Cost, pd.Month_Name,pd.Company_Name,
GROUP_CONCAT(bike_details.Product) + '('+COUNT(*)+')' AS 'SomeColumnName' ,pd.Quantity,pd.Bill_Amount,pd.Due_Date 
FROM payment_details pd INNER JOIN bike_details ON pd.SPDNO = bike_details.SPDNO WHERE pd.SPDNO='5000
group by pd.SPDNO,bike_details.Cost, pd.Month_Name,pd.Company_Name,
pd.Quantity,pd.Bill_Amount,pd.Due_Date
```

Comment: it gives me two rows but i neet one row

Comment: oh, thought you wanted row per colour. mysql seems to have a group_concat for strings, i think you can do  GROUP_CONCAT(bike_details.Product) + '('+COUNT(*)+')' but i dont have a mysql server installed to try

Comment: still it gives me two rows

Comment: did you replace both the bite_deltails.product and count(*) from the original query?

Comment: can you show me what the output is? is the aggregate not working? or is there another column where there are differences?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216503/discussion-between-umair-and-repr).